# Want to modify the laptop video coming from camera and going to teams on linux

Tags: python, linux, microsoft-teams

I use MS teams on linux and it doesn't allow background effects or blurred backgrounds. So I just thought that if I can apply background effect through python script in real time video streaming coming through web cam and going to MS teams.
So is there some sort of hook or way to change the video input for MS teams between MS teams and webcam?
Please direct me towards right resources or direction. Let me know if question is unclear.

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/411897/using-desktop-as-fake-webcam-on-linux).

Comment: Another option is to use OBS as a virtual webcam, and get blurring through a plugin.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT no not yet resolved only got comments telling about similar questions but didn't find something that solve the problem, just some directions so I will look into it further but to me it seems like they will not be solving the problem or at-least not the way I will looking at it.